# Aplicar el estilo de text-decoration solo para ::after

Tags: css, css3, extensión-google-chrome

Para facilitar cómo modifico visualmente una página, por código estoy agregando una clase a ciertos elementos que me interesa marcar. Al agregarles `.marcado`, quedan así:

```css
/* CSS de la página */
p {
  font-size: 18pt;
  text-decoration: underline double darkorange;
}

/* CSS inyectado por mi extensión */
p.marcado::after {
  content: 'marca';
  margin-left: 2ch;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;  /* ESTO NO ME FUNCIONA !!!!! */
}
```

```html
<p>Párrafo uno</p>

<p class="marcado">Párrafo dos</p>  <!-- Acá le agregué la clase -->

<p class="marcado">Párrafo tres</p> <!-- Acá le agregué la clase -->

<p>Párrafo cuatro<p>
```

No puedo hacer que el subrayado de `text-decoration` se mantenga en el párrafo y no aparezca en el pseudoelemento `::after`.

Quiero evitar agregarlos como elementos independientes (por ejemplo en un `<span>`).

¿Cómo puedo hacer que el párrafo se mantenga subrayado y la "marca" no?

Comment: Intentar con `display: inline-block;`

Comment: @Dev.Joel parece funcionar, pero ¿por qué? ¿Qué tiene que ver `display` con el subrayado? No entiendo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al agregar contenido con `after` y `before` los estilos se añaden del elemento padre *p* como se [especifica aquí](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html)

> ¿Cómo puedo hacer que el párrafo se mantenga subrayado y la "marca"
>   no?

Con la propiedad `display: inline-block`deshace el `text-decoration` , pero se preguntará que tiene que ver el `text-decoration` con el display ? pues mucho dado que en la [documentación](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/text.html#propdef-text-decoration) especifica a que elementos no afecta el `text-decoration` y uno de estos es el `inline-block`